# Navbar Collapse on Scroll

Tags: html, navbar

I am trying to have my navbar dropdown collapse when I scroll on the page. I want the navbar still to show on the stop as sticky but after clicking a scrollspy or scroll I would like the navbar to collapse.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  smart-scroll sticky-top bg-body-success justify-content-center">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><strong>Dinos & Francesco's Pizza-Pasta</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="Menu.html"><strong>Menu</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="Catering.html"><strong>Catering Menu</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="ContactUs.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1"><strong>Starters</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2"><strong>Burgers</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3"><strong>Sandwiches & Wraps</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4"><strong>Platters</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading5"><strong>Extraordinary Entrees</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6"><strong>Hoagies</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7"><strong>Pizza</strong></a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading8"><strong>Daily Specials</strong></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```